# count how many times a word occurs in a file and also in which lines?

Tags: regex, perl

let be explain In a text file "script.txt" i have to find "foo" word how many times of it Occurrence and in which lines and i have to list that lines.

Comment: my $val = <"data.txt">;
chomp ($val);
my $cnt=0;
open (HNDL, "$val") || die "wrong filename";
while ($val = <HNDL>)
{
  while ($val =~ /\bis\b/ig)
  {
    ++$cnt;
        
}
}
print "Number of instances of 'is' found: $cnt\n\n";
print "$.: $val\n";
close (HNDL);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follow

```
my $total;
my $lines;
open my $fh,"<","file.txt";
while (<DATA>)
{
    if(my $ech_count = () = /\bfoo\b/g)
    {
        $total+=$ech_count;
        $lines.=$.."\n";
    }

}
print " Total count : $total\nLines are: \n $lines";
```

In above script `$ech_count` stores the number of matches in a lines it is perform by the `= () =`.

`$.` It is the perl inbuild special variable which give the current line number.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines = <DATA>;
my ($word_count, $total) = '';
foreach my $single(@lines)
{
    if($single=~m/\bfoo\b/g)
    {
        $word_count = $single=~s/\bfoo\b/$&/g;
        print "Line Matched: $single\n";
        $total = $total + $word_count;
    }
}
print "Foo Count: $total\n";
```